# Oracle query - Selecting unique row number based on order of another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find the best way to make a query with two columns, one is a number and the order a date:

Doing a select and ordering by the date column.

**Table1**:

| col1 (NUMBER) | col2 (DATE) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 02/2019 |
| 2 | 02/2019 |
| 3 | 02/2019 |
| 4 | 03/2019 |
| 2 | 04/2019 |
| 3 | 05/2019 |

I'm doing a query like this:

```sql
select col1, col2
from table1
order by col2 asc, col1 asc
fetch next 10;
```

The result I'm getting is also getting the next day's values, and repeating the value on col1 result like this:

| col1 (NUMBER) | col2 (DATE) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 02/2019 |
| 2 | 02/2019 |
| 3 | 02/2019 |
| 4 | 03/2019 |
| 2 | 04/2019 |
| 3 | 05/2019 |

But I would like a filter to limit to only a sequential col1 value like this:

| col1 (NUMBER) | col2 (DATE) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 02/2019 |
| 2 | 02/2019 |
| 3 | 02/2019 |
| 4 | 03/2019 |

ignoring values that would come in a "next batch" and not going through the risk of repeating col1 values, or getting col1 values that have a bigger col2 value than a previous result.

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use a cumulative `max()`:

```
select col1, col2
from (select t1.*,
             max(col1) over (order by col2, col1 rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as running_max
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
where running_max is null or col1 > running_max;
```

This returns rows whose value is greater than the values on the preceding rows.

EDIT:

If you want to return rows only up to the *first* time there is a decline, then:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             sum(case when prev_col1 > col1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by col2, col1) as num_decreases
      from (select t1.*,
                   lag(col1) over (order by col2, col1) as prev_col1
            from table1 t1
           ) t1
where num_decreases = 0;
```